# How to create query for items created on current iteration

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

Working with Azure DevOps Server, I'd like to have an ongoing dashboard that will automatically update each day/week and especially iteration (sprint).
I'm seeking for a solution to see all work items (ex. bug) that were created in the timeframe of @currentIteration.

If I'd use the "Created Date" field (ex: >= 1/1/22 AKA sprint start day), on the following sprint I'd have to update this field (and over again each sprint).

Is there an option to combine these two fields together, so it will be automatic for each iteration (ex: Created Date - @StartOfCurrentIteration)?

I'd like to know if there is a different option/solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

@currentIteration is a macros designed for the Iteration Path field. Currently, Create Date field does not support @currentIteration.

You can use the @currentIteration to find any item assigned to a sprint that corresponds to the current iteration path for the team.

For more information about @currentIteration, please refer the link : [Query by date or current iteration in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops-2019)

If you need the feature, you can try to [request a feature for Azure DevOps Server (TFS) here.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?from=email&viewtype=all&space=22&entry=suggestion)